# How to find Paypal IPN chargeaback flow

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to identify all **chargeback** IPN requests from paypal. So far only think I can figure out is 
Txn_Type=new_case & Case_type in (chargeback,dispute,complaint) distinct invoices are chargeback requests. You can join them with `txnid` and `parenttxnid`.

But there are cases where txn_type is null but `reason_code` in (chargeback,buyer_complaint or admin_fraud_reversal) with PaymentStatus=Reversed

Is there any rule to identify all the chargeback cases? Or better a flow diagram for all possible scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

According to PayPal documentation here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

You should receive an IPN POST with this value:

> transaction_type = Adjustment

This can be for a chargeback, reversal, or refund; check the **[reason_code](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EBC0E05Z)** to see which it is.

You may need to customize your script with additional IPN variables in order to receive additional data.

Please find here the Guide for integration: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding based on [IPN and PDT Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/), you can identify chargeback by:

- `txn_type` doesn't exist
- `case_type` is `chargeback`

If you want to know further, you can then find out the reason by looking into the [`reason_code`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EBC0E05Z__id0913D0D0K4E).